# Print multiple documents and finish all of them with stapler using lp in linux?

Tags: printing, cups, lp, hplip

I'm using this command to print multiple files with lp in linux but each document is being finished with stapler:

```
lp -d printername -o "HPPaperSource=Tray3" -o "HPStaplerOptions=1StapleRightAngled" /file/1.pdf /file/2.pdf
```

Printer driver is HPLIP.

What i want to achieve is to finish both documents with one staple and not each document with one staple.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `lpr` on a set of two files, it runs a separate instance on each of the files.  In order to achieve the effect you need, you need to combine the files into one.

```
pdftk file1.pdf file2.pdf output out.pdf
```

If the first file has an odd number of pages, you will first need to create a pdf with an empty page (with LibreOffice/OpenOffice, inkscape, (La)TeX, scribus, etc.), and include the empty page file between `file1.pdf` and `file2.pdf`.

Once the files are combined, then you can print them as a single file, which will give you the result you seek.