# How to print a document and finish with stapler in Linux/Unix?

Tags: linux, lp

Is it possible to print a document & staple it using the lp command in Linux/Unix?  If there are other ways in *nix, I am open for options.

Linux  : Oracle Linux Server release 6.5

Printer: Ricoh MP C4504

I tried the "HPStaplerOptions=1StapleRightAngled" option mentioned in below discussion but it did not work.

[Print multiple documents and finish all of them with stapler using lp in linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440895/print-multiple-documents-and-finish-all-of-them-with-stapler-using-lp-in-linux)

This is the command I tried.

```
lp -c -d0321 -n1 -o "HPStaplerOptions=1StapleRightAngled" testpage.pdf
```

And here are the reported options from `lpoptions -p 0321`:

```
auth-info-required=none copies=1 device-uri=lpd://print.company.com/0321?timeout=60 finishings=3
job-hold-until=no-hold job-priority=50 job-sheets=none,none marker-change-time=0
number-up=1 printer-info=0321 printer-is-accepting-jobs=true
printer-is-shared=true printer-location printer-make-and-model='Local Raw Printer'
printer-state=3 printer-state-change-time=1666715772 printer-state-reasons=none printer-type=4
printer-uri-supported=ipp://localhost:631/printers/0321
```

Thanks.

Comment: post the output of `lpoptions -l` (use the `-p` option with the desintation printer name if it's not default), or at least those options that seem to do with stapling

Comment: I don’t think the LaserJet 4 series included printers big enough to include a stapler unit, so the HPLJ4SI PPD may not include stapler commands at all. If you are using some other printer model which claims downwards-compatibility with HP LJ 4Si, you might have to look for a PPD specific to that actual model (or model series) to access functions like the stapler.

Comment: @telcoM You are right.  I was told the compatibility is HPLJ4Si but I found the printer is actually Ricoh MP C4504.  Let me correct this in my original post too.

Comment: @telcoM talking about PPDs, I found the PPDs for the above printer here.  how can I leverage this?

https://www.openprinting.org/download/PPD/Ricoh/

Comment: lpoptions -p 0321
auth-info-required=none copies=1 device-uri=lpd://print.company.com/0321?timeout=60 finishings=3 job-hold-until=no-hold job-priority=50 job-sheets=none,none marker-change-time=0 number-up=1 printer-info=0321 printer-is-accepting-jobs=true printer-is-shared=true printer-location printer-make-and-model='Local Raw Printer' printer-state=3 printer-state-change-time=1666715772 printer-state-reasons=none printer-type=4 printer-uri-supported=ipp://localhost:631/printers/0321

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ricoh MP C4504, the [OpenPrinting database](https://www.openprinting.org/printer/Ricoh/Ricoh-MP_C4504) has multiple PPD files available. The recommended one is PDF-based, but since you are using Oracle Linux 6.5, you might perhaps need the PostScript or PCL-XL version; try the PDF version first and see if it works for you.

Download the appropriate PPD file from the OpenPrinting database, then use

```
lpadmin -p 0321 -P /path/to/the/file.ppd
```

to switch your existing print queue to use the new PPD.

Then run `lpoptions -p 0321 -l`: on one of the lines, it should list the Finisher option, e.g. something like

```
Finisher/Finisher: *NotInstalled FinRUBICONB FinVOLGADBK FinVOLGAD FinAMURBBK FinAMURHY
```

The asterisk indicates the currently selected option.

In the PPD file, this option is defined as:

```
*OpenUI *Finisher/Finisher: PickOne
*DefaultFinisher: NotInstalled
*Finisher NotInstalled/Not Installed: ""
*Finisher FinRUBICONB/Finisher SR3130: ""
*Finisher FinVOLGADBK/Finisher SR3240: ""
*Finisher FinVOLGAD/Finisher SR3230: ""
*Finisher FinAMURBBK/Finisher SR3220: ""
*Finisher FinAMURHY/Finisher SR3210: ""
*CloseUI: *Finisher
```

So, apparently `FinRUBICONB` could be Ricoh's internal project name to the finisher that is officially known as "Finisher SR3130". The stapler is usually part of the finisher unit: you'll need to figure out which type of finisher unit your printer has, then use `lpadmin -p 0321 -o Finisher=FinRUBICONB` (or whatever matches your actual finisher model) to specify your printer's finisher type.

To find out your printer's finisher type, try using the printer's control panel to get a configuration report printed: it will usually include a list of installed options, and the finisher type should be listed there. Alternatively, you might need to do some physical inspection: the finisher is usually a distinct module with a model number visible somewhere, although it might be inside a door or behind the printer. If all else fails, you could try the finisher types one at a time and see which one works for you and allows the use of all the features your printer+finisher has.

After the finisher type is configured, you should be able to use the stapler.

The options for the stapler are also defined in the PPD file like this:

```
*JCLOpenUI *StapleLocation/Staple: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 100 JCLSetup *StapleLocation
*DefaultStapleLocation: None
*StapleLocation None/Off: "@PJL SET STAPLE=OFF<0A>"
*StapleLocation StaplessUpperLeft/Top left (stapleless): "@PJL SET STAPLE=STAPLELESSLEFTTOPSLANTPORT<0A>"
*StapleLocation StaplessUpperRight/Top right (stapleless): "@PJL SET STAPLE=STAPLELESSRIGHTTOPSLANTPORT<0A>"
*StapleLocation UpperLeft/Top left: "@PJL SET STAPLE=LEFTTOP<0A>"
*StapleLocation UpperRight/Top right: "@PJL SET STAPLE=RIGHTTOP<0A>"
*StapleLocation LeftW/2 at left: "@PJL SET STAPLE=LEFT2PORT<0A>"
*StapleLocation RightW/2 at right: "@PJL SET STAPLE=RIGHT2PORT<0A>"
*StapleLocation UpperW/2 at top: "@PJL SET STAPLE=TOP2PORT<0A>"
*StapleLocation CenterW/2 at center: "@PJL SET STAPLE=BOOKLET<0A>"
*JCLCloseUI: *StapleLocation
```

You should see the options also in the `lpoptions -p 0321 -l` output. However, since this is not a HP printer, the configuration options are worded a bit differently and not prefixed with the letters `HP`.

Based on the above PPD snippet, the syntax for you would be similar to:

```
lp -d0321 -n1 -o "StapleLocation=UpperLeft" testpage.pdf
```

You might have to try the other StapleLocation options: a specific finisher unit might be able to implement only some of them.

The `StapleLocation=CenterW` is specific to booklet-type finishers: I would hazard a guess that those would be the `Fin*BK` finishers. A booklet finisher is more complex (= expensive) than a non-booklet one, so I would not expect to find a booklet finisher unless there was a definite need for one.

It might be more convenient to set the printer options using the web GUI at `http://localhost:631` (or `https://localhost:631`), or using some other GUI configuration tool if you have them installed, but the above is the hard-core way of doing it with command-line only. The advantage of it is that it always works, whether you have GUI access available or not.

If your application only takes a printer queue name, you might use the `lpoptions` command to define multiple "instances"/option sets for the base printer queue, e.g. `lpoptions -p 0321/stapled2side -o StapleLocation=whatever -o sides=two-sided-long-edge` or whatever, then just tell the application to use printer queue `0321/stapled2side` instead of the base queue `0321`. You can define several instances for each main queue, each with a different set of options. To list the instances you've already defined, you can use `sudo grep Dest /etc/cups/lpoptions`.

Comment: OMG!!! Hats off to you Sir!! We are making some progress. How do I find my printer's finisher unit?

Comment: That may require some physical inspection: if there seems to be a distinct "module" in the printer where the paper comes out, that is most likely the finisher. Usually there is a model number label somewhere, but it might be behind the unit or otherwise out of sight. Another possibility is if you can use the printer's control panel to request a printed configuration report: it usually includes a list of installed options, including the type of finisher unit. If all else fails, you could try all the finisher type settings one at a time, and see which one works.

Comment: telcoM - You are amazing and you had answers to all my questions!! I was able to print and staple the pages. Like you said the PDF one did not work as the printer was PCL-XL. After printing the printer configuration, I got the finisher information too. And then my life was easy. Thank You Thank You Thank You for all your help!!!

Comment: Now I need to find out how to configure this in Oracle EBS so that the concurrent program will make use of these commands in CUPS.

Comment: If the Oracle EBS only takes a printer queue name, you might use the `lpoptions` command to define multiple "instances"/option sets for the base printer queue, e.g. `lpoptions -p 0321/stapled2side -o StapleLocation=whatever -o sides=two-sided-long-edge` or whatever, then just tell Oracle EBS to use printer queue `0321/stapled2side` instead of the base queue `0321`. You can define several instances for each main queue, each with a different set of options. To list the instances you've already defined, you can use `sudo grep Dest /etc/cups/lpoptions`

Comment: I was able to use the printer style in Oracle EBS where I used the lp command to print after loading lpadmin -p 0321 -P C4504-pxlcolor-Ricoh.ppd driver.

Now how do I delete/remove the configuration that I have loaded, if I wanted to?

Comment: I'm confused: "printer style" seems to be Oracle EBS settings. Are you asking about removing the EBS printer style you've configured, or the CUPS-level PPD setting? If it's the latter, setting a different PPD with `lpadmin -P` will override the old one. To remove options from a instance defined with `lpoptions`, use e.g. `lpoptions -p 0321/stapled2side -r sides`, or to remove the entire instance, use `lpoptions -x 0321/stapled2side`. If you use `lpoptions -x 0321` it removes all the options from the base printer queue at once. For EBS, maybe ask a separate question, perhaps in Server Fault.SE?

Comment: Sorry - I should have been more clear.  What is the command to undo the below?

`lpadmin -p 0321 -P /path/to/the/file.ppd`

Comment: If you set a new PPD, it will completely replace the old one. If you want to go back to a no-PPD-assigned "raw" queue using the command line, the easiest way is probably to stop CUPS, `sudo rm /etc/cups/ppd/0321.ppd*` (that's where CUPS copies the selected PPD to when you use `lpadmin -P`), and make sure there is no interface script either: `sudo rm /etc/cups/interfaces/0321`, then restart CUPS. Now the queue is again a "raw" queue, just as if no PPD was ever configured for the queue.

Comment: [This question and its answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12271871/9197000) refer to this too.

Comment: Once again thanks for helping this newbie.  Appreciate all the help and support.  Best wishes.